# Make Deskptop files executable

Tags: gnome, executable

I’m running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.  Learned how to do a screen fetch and got the following results.

/Desktop$ screenfetch
MY MACHINE

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-66-generic

Uptime: 6h 29m

Packages: 1917

Shell: bash 5.0.17

Resolution: 3840x1080

DE: GNOME 3.36.5

WM: Mutter

WM Theme: Adwaita

GTK Theme: Yaru-light [GTK2/3]

Icon Theme: Yaru

Font: Ubuntu 11

Disk: 53G / 1.8T (4%)

CPU: AMD A8-6500 APU with Radeon HD Graphics @ 4x 3.5GHz

GPU: AMD/ATI Richland [Radeon HD 8570D]

RAM: 1757MiB / 7147MiB

I have a folder on my desktop named JMRI (Java Model Railroad Interface).  Within that folder there are three files that need to be executable on my Desktop:
file1
file2
file3
I have copied the three files to my Desktop.  How do I make these three files executable?

Wish this would be standard rather than having to "jump through hoops".

Thanks,
Rich Ramik

Answer (score 0):

It is not a matter of having to "jump through hoops". It is just a matter of making the file executable. To do that, right-click the file, select "Properties", then the "Permissions" tab.

Whether you can directly run executables by double-clicking on executable files on the desktop is a different matter. Increasingly, launching files from everywhere is not anymore supported in Gnome Shell for security reasons. Instead, place the executables (or a link to them) in `~/bin` or `~/.local/bin` so you can easily load them from the terminal or the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> command dialog. Alternatively, create `.desktop` launchers for these executables in `~/.local/share/applications`, so you have access from the Activities overview or the Application overview, where you could place them on the Dock for quick access.

If a classical fully active desktop is crucial to your workflow, then consider moving to another desktop environment such as Mate, XFCE or Cinnamon. While the default Ubuntu desktop tries to restore desktop functionality, it uses a system that does not support that out of the box. That is why the active desktop in Ubuntu is limited in several ways.